# Which classes should I turn to beans in a Spring project?

Tags: java, spring

I'm learning a spring framework and I have a question. When I create a Java/Spring project, which classes should I choose to describe as beans in Spring xml? For example: if I want to access DB table called Student, I create these classes: `Student`, `StudentMapper` (implements RowMapper) and `StudentJDBCTemplate` (DAO). Should I describe every these classes in my project as Spring Beans? What are the criterias for choosing class to describe it as Spring Bean?

Comment: 1) Don't use the XML. This is obsolete, there is absolutely no point in learning things that are already outdated. Use Spring 4 and use annotations. 2) Almost all of them. Anything with business logic should be abstracted by an `interface` and injected. Once you understand the implications of doing this, you can begin to make more informed decisions - but that's a good rule to start with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule is if an object has a reference to another object, then both should be beans to have the second injected in the first. I suppose you will have a DAO and a service. Both must be beans and do not forget that an injected bean should allways be declared through an interface. This rule is not absolute but it will allow you to easyly use AOP if you need to, and is anyway a good practice in java programming.

In contrast, `Student` has normally no reason to be a bean (should not be injected nor have anything injected into), and the `RowMapper` implementation can simply be an inner class of the Dao because it should never be used elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following strict spring framework make bean of  ServiceImpl and DaoImpl.